# Select rows where one cell value is equal to parameter or everything in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons p
WHERE p.Name= ISNULL(@Name, p.Name)
```

it `@Name` is null it only selects the rows where `Name` is not NULL but not the one with `NULL` value.

What has to be done to select desired rows?

Comment: http://imgur.com/b8i9FLP like this when name parameter value is null, but i get only ones with name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @name varchar(290) ='Thomas'

SELECT * FROM 
Persons P
WHERE exists(select name intersect select coalesce(@name, name))
```

Answer (score 1):

When `@Name` is `NULL` the query became

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons P 
WHERE p.Name = p.Name
```

and `NULL` is not equal `NULL`, as it mean unknown value and two unknown values are not equal.

A way to get all the data is

```
SELECT *
FROM   Persons P
WHERE  COALESCE(p.Name, N'a') = COALESCE(@Name, p.Name, N'a')
```

so that when p.Name is `NULL` there is a default value to use.

**Edit** as the string `'NULL'` as the last value of `COALESCE` can be confusing I changed it to another constant literal.

Comment: also `'NULL'` does not equal `NULL`

Comment: Ah, Sorry, good you cleared that up! Read a little to fast over your post ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to show all entries, if `@name is null` and if it is not, show only the values that share the same value as `@name`, this should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE @name IS NOT NULL AND name = @name OR @name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
SELECT * FROM Persons p
WHERE p.Name= coalesce(@Name, p.Name)
```

Comment: There is no functional difference between this and the query of the OP

Comment: could you post some input data and reqired output,its taking hard time to understand whts this !

Comment: I posted a simple screen in comments of original post which is what I want when `@Name` is `null` and when it is not `null` I want rows where Name == @Name

Comment: @pepela your screenshot is confusing as it shows `one entry that has a non-null-name` and all `other entries have null value for name`, does that mean if `@name is null` you want all entries? or only the ones that have null-values?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste when `@Name` is null I want all entries.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you need this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons p
WHERE (p.Name= ISNULL(@Name, p.Name) OR Name IS NULL)
```

Comment: this does not work when @Name has value, it selects rows with this value and all other with NULL values

Answer (score 0):

Write as:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons p
WHERE 1 = case when isnull(@Name,'') = '' then 1 
          when isnull(@Name,'') <> '' and p.Name = @Name  then 1 
          end
```